# How to install MaTeX on Mathematica online?

Tags: packages, latex, wolfram-cloud, mathematica-online

Can you please tell me the step-by-step procedure to install MaTeX on Mathematica Online platform?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is not possible. I do think that I could do this on a [Wolfram Enterprise Private Cloud](https://www.wolfram.com/enterprise-private-cloud/) virtual machine, but that is expensive ( though I think WRI should just donate one for MSE people to play with and e.g. install MaTeX and other nice way-ahead-of-standard-Mathematica-packages software ... ).

Comment: @RolfMertig I think you can do this if you manually copy up the .paclet file and unzip it with `ExtractArchive`. Might need a `PacletDirectoryAdd` in there too.

Comment: @b3m2a1 But how do you install LaTeX and ghostscript and convince WRI you are allowed to call that ...

Comment: @b3m2a1 Can you execute LibraryLink on the public cloud? I don't think so ...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90283/discussion-on-question-by-andreapaco-how-to-install-matex-on-mathematica-online).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MaTeX relies on an external TeX system. Since this cannot be installed in Wolfram Cloud, MaTeX would not be usable either.